# WFS from GeoServer won't open in QGIS

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I'm trying to open an WFS from my GeoServer in QGIS. But with very little success.  I'm getting an error: 
"Error when parsing GetFeature response : Error: not well-formed (invalid token) on line 1"

Searching this error indicates it could be an encoding issue... 
My data is on a PostGIS database with encoding = Latin1, and my GeoServer is set to UTF-8. Could be the problem, but changing GeoServer global settings to "ISO-8859-1" which should be equal to latin1, does not help.

Any ideas that might fix it?

postgis version: 9.4.10
geroserver version : 2.11.1
qgis version 2.18.7

Comment: Have you checked the geoserver logs?

Comment: Yes - but I'm afraid it's not clear text to me...

Comment: the first lines looks like this:

Oops, something went wrong...

Sorry, something unexpected happened on the server.



Here's an error report you can include in a JIRA bug report about this issue: 
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Exception in rendering component: [TextArea [Component id = logs]]
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2625)
 at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1668)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2401)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2329)

Comment: So thats a bug (or misconfiguration) on the server side. I have no idea what it is from that part of the stacktrace. Suggest filing a JIRA ticket on the geoserver bug tracker, including exactly how you configured GeoServer, what the full stacktrace shows, what the data source is, what the specific layer configuration is, and anything else that is specific to that layer.

Comment: Ok - I'l tjek with our suppliers on the geoserver. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: do wfs requests work in the browser?

Comment: I found the same problem described from the author of the initial question, but following the suggestion provided by the answers it still doesn't work for me.
I have checked the enconding on postGIS and geoserver layer and they are both UTF-8,
I renamed the workspace, source and layer using just letters (not even underscores)
but I still get the same message: 'Error when parsing GetFeature response : Error: not well-formed (invalid token) on line 1,'
Is anybody in my same situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a same problem. In Geoserver I had layers with names that contained spaces and dashes. When I renamed them using only letters and underscore, problem was gone.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the [answer from Zoran Petrović](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/247290/107424), it will also not open if the layer starts with a number.

Comment: This was my issue. Sounds like a QGIS issue, any idea if there is an open ticket? It's still an issue with QGIS 3.24